# Cordova Project build error in netbeans

Tags: netbeans, cordova, netbeans-7, cordova-3

I am getting this an error when I build my project even though is an empty project

```
> TypeError: Arguments to path.join must be strings
>     at f (path.js:204:15)
>     at Object.filter (native)
>     at Object.exports.join (path.js:209:40)
>     at possiblyFetch (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\plugman\src\install.js:49:27)
>     at C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\plugman\src\install.js:298:17
>     at Array.forEach (native)
>     at runInstall (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\plugman\src\install.js:229:22)
>     at possiblyFetch (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\plugman\src\install.js:64:9)
>     at Object.installPlugin [as install] (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\plugman\src\install.js:44:5)
>     at doInstall (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\src\plugin.js:153:45)
```

I have follow some advise at google , but non of them is working .

Comment: Hit the same problem, using Netbeans 7.4 RC2.